# How to bind drop-down list to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, razor, model

I learn ASP.NET and I try to bind my drop-down list to model, where user set some value in view, controller set this value to model that connect to database.

I've tried to use Request.Form, but it doesnt work for drop-down.

View

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="post">
            <p>
                Quantity of people:
                <select name="quantity" class="form-control">
                    <option>Quantity of people</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>



            <p>
                Choose class of your apartment:
                @Html.DropDownList("Class",
                         new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Classes))),
                         "Choose class",
                         new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("class")



            <p>
                Date of your arrival:
                <input id="startdate" class="form-control" type="date" name="start">


            <p>
                Date of your departure:
                <input id="enddate" class="form-control" type="date" name="end">


                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default"   />
            </p>

        </form>
```

Model:

```
public class UserBook
    {
        public int UserBookId { get; set; }
        public int UserQuantity { get; set; }
        public UserClasses UserClass { get; set; }
        public DateTime UserDateTimeStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime UserDateTimeEnd { get; set; }


        public enum UserClasses
        {
            Econom,
            Standart,
            Luxury
        }

    }
```

In controller I understand that i need to do 
class instance like

```
 IRepository<Apartment> dbshow;
        IRepository<UserBook> dbrec;
        public HomeController()
        {
            dbshow = new BookingRepository();
            dbrec = new RequestRepository();
        }
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserRequest(UserClasses? Class, int? quantity, DateTime? start, DateTime? end, )
        {

            UserBook u = new UserBook();
            u.UserQuantity = quantity.GetValueOrDefault();
            u.UserClass = Class.GetValueOrDefault();
            u.UserDateTimeStart = start.GetValueOrDefault();
            u.UserDateTimeEnd = end.GetValueOrDefault();



            ViewData["CurrentQuan"] = quantity;
            ViewData["CurrentClass"] = Class;
            ViewData["CurrentStart"] = start;
            ViewData["CurrentEnd"] = end;




            if (quantity.HasValue)
            {

            }
            else { ModelState.AddModelError("", "Input number of people"); }

            if (Class.HasValue)
            {

            }
            else { ModelState.AddModelError("", "Input class of apartment"); }

            if (start.HasValue)
            {
            }
            else { ModelState.AddModelError("", "Введите дату заезда"); }

            if (end.HasValue)
            {
            }
            else { ModelState.AddModelError("", "Input arrival date"); }

            if (start < DateTime.Now || end < DateTime.Now)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Date isn't correct");
            }

            if (start >= end)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Date of arrival and departure isn't valid");
            }
            dbrec.Update(u);
            return View();
        }
```

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Pls add full controller code for post method in question

Comment: @AA  I've added, check it.

Comment: Try like this u.UserQuantity =quantity!=null?quantity:0

Comment: @AA sorry, i have ```int?``` not just ```int``` in parameters of controller, so this isnt work. I need to keep ```int?``` because i have checked ```quantity.HasValue ```

Comment: For that int? i gave a ternary operator.  If you want quanity.HasValue, do like if(quantity.HasValue)
            {u.UserQuantity =quantity;

            }

Comment: @AA yes, i understand, but for int? your ternary operator doesnt work. Error: 
cannot convert int? type to int type

Comment: u.UserQuantity = quantity.GetValueOrDefault(); or u.UserQuantity = quantity.HasValue ? (int)quantity.Value : (int?)null;

Comment: @AA thanks, the compiler does not throw an error but when i start my project, it 
complains on my ```dbrec.Update(u)```  Error: ```An object reference does not indicate an instance of an object.``` Mu modify code i edit in my quewstion

Comment: Pls accept the answer

Comment: What is this dbrec?

Comment: @AA my empty database, that build with ```UserBook``` model

Comment: @AA maybe problem in view, button Send doesn't have some method

Comment: Where do you defined dbrec in UserRequest?

Comment: @AA thanks, i forgot to defined it, i have no error, but my db still empty after  sending my inputs on site. You can check how i defined, i added it to my question. But i think problem in some other things

Comment: @AA it's all ok, i just forggot to add dbrec.Save(); THANK YOU!!!!! You are good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 u.UserQuantity = quantity.GetValueOrDefault();
```